# Adding visual time markers to the player bar of a video

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, psychopy

I'm trying to program an experiment in which I want to find out how humans cognitively segment movement streams. For example, if the movement stream could is a person climbing a flight of stairs, each step might be a single segment.
The study is bascially a replication of this one here, but with another set of stimuli: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2010325.2010326

Each trial should be structured like the following:

1. Present a video of a motion stream. Display a bar beneath the video that has a marker that moves in sync with the current time of the video (very similar to GUI of a video player).
2. Present that video again, but now let the participant add stationary markers to the bar beneath the video by pressing a key. The marker is supposed to be placed at the time point in the video bar that corresponds with the time the buttom was pressed (e.g. when the video is 100 seconds long and the buttom was pressed 10 seconds into the video, it should be placed at the 10% mark of the bar).

My instructor suggested programming the whole thing using PsychoPy. PsychoPy currently only supports Python 2.7.
I've looked into the program and it looks promising. One can display a video easily and the [rating scale](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/ratingscale.html) class is similar to the bar we want to implement. However, several features are missing, namely:

- One can only set a single marker, subjects should be able to set multiples
- As mentioned in point (1) we want to have a marker that moves in synch with the video.
- When a key press occurs a marker should be placed at the point in the bar that corresponds with the current time point in the video.

Hence my questions: Do you have any tips for implementing the features described above using the PsychoPy module?

I don't know how much this gets into recommendation question territory, but in case you know of a module for writing experiment GUIs that has widgets with the features we want for this experiment I would be curious to hear about them.

Comment: You might want to take this to the discourse.psychopy.org forum as it is better set up for discussion and ongoing support rather than the single question/single answer format here.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill That's a good point. I didn't think of the fact that this isn't a one and done question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PsychoPy is a good choice for this. The rating scale however (as you note) is probably not the right tool for creating the markers. You can make simple polygon shapes though, which could serve as your multiple markers as well as the continuous time indicator.

e.g. you could make a polygon stimulus with three vertices (to make a triangle indicator) and set its location to be something like this (assuming you are using normalised coordinates):

`$[((t/movie_duration) * 2 - 1) , -0.9]`

`t` is a Builder variable that represents the time elapsed in the current trial in seconds. The centre of the screen is at coordinates `[0, 0]`. So the code above would make the pointer move smoothly from the left hand edge of the screen to the right, close to the bottom edge of the screen, reaching the right hand edge once the move ends. Set the polygon's position field to update every frame so that the animation is continuous.

`movie_duration` is a placeholder variable for the duration of the movie in seconds. You could specify this in your conditions file, or you can query the movie component to get its duration I think, something like:

`$[((t/movie_stim_name.duration()) * 2 - 1) , -0.9]`

You could leave markers on the screen in response to keypresses in a similar way, but this would require a little Python code in a code component.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I have a couple of questions, though:

Comment: Sry, I accidently hit "Enter" and then took too long to edit. Here is part deux:
**1.** If (0,0) is the center of the screen, then wouldn't your code snippet move the polygon pointer towards said center and not towards the right hand edge, since the x coordinate starts at -1 and ends at 0?
**2.** I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not quite sure what do you mean with "query"? I know that a MovieStim has an attribute .duration that is the length of the movie.
Btw: I've have a decent amount of programming experience in Python, so working at the code and not GUI level is definitively an option.

Comment: You were right about the arithmetic, there needed to be a factor of 2 in there to get it all the way to the right side. Have also added a version showing how you could access the movie duration directly.

Comment: It worked well. Only one small correction: .duration() produces an error, since .duration is an attribute, not a function. Remove the parantheses and it works fine.